Creating Bullets with VBA in Word from Access leads to odd behavior
I am creating a Monthly Report function that outputs to a Word document to a daily task Access database.  However I'm seeing odd behavior when creating the bullet points.
*** I know that I can create reports but I don't want to =)  The formatting didn't look the same***
Code explanation:
I have a button on a form that kicks off Sub btnCreateReport_Click()
Within that I created a Sub to clean up the paragraph / bullet creation called Sub fnNewPara
Additionally,  I created another function that will eventually pull the text data from a database called Function fnGetActivities()
I use ParaIsSubBullet as a counter of how many indents I'm going to implement at a given line.
It's easy to see how it's skewed in the attached image.
Problem being is that if I just pass a blank string or blank space as text it formats perfectly.
If I add any text then it skews after the first iteration of the sub sub bullet.
side by side comparison of the text output
Here is the code:
Sub fnNewPara( _
n As Integer, _
ParaText As Variant, _
ParaFont As String, _
ParaFontSize As Integer, _
paraUnderline As Boolean, _
paraBold As Boolean, _
ParaIsBullet As Boolean, _
ParaIsSubBullet As Integer, _
ParaAlign As Integer, _
wdDoc As Object _
)

    wdDoc.Paragraphs.Add
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(n).Range.Text = ParaText & vbNewLine
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(n).Range.Font.Name = ParaFont
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(n).Range.Font.Size = ParaFontSize
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(n).Range.Font.Underline = paraUnderline
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(n).Range.Font.Bold = paraBold
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(n).Format.Alignment = ParaAlign
    
    If ParaIsBullet = True Then
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(n).Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
    End If
    
    If ParaIsSubBullet > 0 Then
    Do Until ParaIsSubBullet = 0
    
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(n).Range.ListFormat.ListIndent
    
    ParaIsSubBullet = ParaIsSubBullet - 1
    Loop
    

    
    End If
    
    If ParaIsOutdent = True Then
    wdDoc.Paragraphs(n).Range.ListFormat.Listoutdent
    End If
    

End Sub

Function fnGetActivities() As String

fnGetActivities = "a" ' adding text to the sub sub bullet creates odd behavior not linked to this function

End Function



Private Sub btnCreateReport_Click()
 
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim ParaFontSize As Integer
    Dim ParaAlign As Integer
    Dim ParaText As String
    Dim ParaFont As String
    Dim strFont As String
    Dim paraUnderline As Boolean
    Dim paraBold As Boolean
    Dim ParaIsBullet As Boolean
    Dim ParaIsSubBullet As Boolean
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim strLocation As Variant
    Dim strSection As Variant
    Dim strYear As String
    Dim strMonth As String
    
    strSection = Array("Section1", "Section2", "Section3")  ' arrays ind start at 0
    strLocation = Array("Location1", "Location2", "Location3")
    
    myFileName = "TestReport.docx"
    myFileDest = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\output\" & myFileName

    strYear = "2024"
    strMonth = "June"
    strFont = "Times new roman"
    
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True ' Make Word application visible
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
       
    '#########################################################
    
    n = 1
    s = 0
    l = 0

  ' fnNewPara (n, Text, Font, FontSize, Underline, Bold, IsBullet, IsSubBullet,IsOutdent,NumofBulletIndents, Align, ObjectDef)
  
    fnNewPara n, "Monthly Activity Report for " & strMonth & " " & strYear, "Times new roman", 12, True, True, False, 0, 1, wdDoc
    n = n + 1

Do Until s > 2
    fnNewPara n, strSection(s), "Times new roman", 12, True, True, True, 1, 0, wdDoc
    n = n + 1
    
    Do Until l > 2
       fnNewPara n, strLocation(l), strFont, 12, False, False, True, 2, 0, wdDoc
       n = n + 1
       fnNewPara n, fnGetActivities, strFont, 12, False, False, True, 3, 0, wdDoc
       n = n + 1
       l = l + 1
    Loop
 s = s + 1
 l = 0
 Loop

    
    '#########################################################
    
    ' Save the document
    'wdDoc.SaveAs myFileDest
    
    ' Optionally, close Word application
    'wdApp.Quit
    
    ' Release the objects
    Set subPara = Nothing
    Set para = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    


I'd say it behaves just like Word does. If you are in a bullet list, add a para with text, it keeps the current indentation. If you add an empty para, it removes one indentation level. You need to keep track of the current indentation, and only call .ListIndent if you actually want to go deeper. If you want to go higher, you may need to use .ListOutdent.

Oh dear, the lengths people go to to avoid using Styles. Just apply the built-in bulleted styles List Bullet - List Bullet 5. If this is a regular report then create a Word template (.dotx) and modify the styles to have the formatting you want. Result = less code and stable formatting.

Solution:  I solved the top skewed output problem by .ListOutdent ing to the base level at each line item and then .ListIndent ing the appropriate number of indents.     In the end I did follow Rylatt's "advice" and figured out Styles (which I didn't know about) and honestly isn't well explained.

It is impossible to use Word without using styles. In your code all of the formatting is applied on top of the default style. For all you need to know about styles, and much more, see: https://shaunakelly.com/
